# Proof Involving Simple Graph

Tags: graph-theory, proof-verification

I have the task of proving that if there is a simple graph with 6 vertices and 13 edges, there is at least one vertex of degree greater than or equal to five.

Given that, $2m = \sum_{v\epsilon V} deg(v)$, then we have $26 = 6*|E|$, then $|E|=26/6$ and by the Pidgeonhole Principle, there is at least one vertex with $\lceil26/6\rceil$ edges.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks valid to me.

If I'm reading this correctly, what you've done is proved that the average vertex degree is $26/6$. $26/6$ is not an integer, so, for it to be an average of integers (the vertex degrees), one of the integers must be more than it, and the smallest integer greater than $26/6$ is $5$.